# Register and Connect links: where are they located?

Tags: login

A trivial question which eludes me:

I want to modify the logic behind showing the Register and Connect link, which appear at the top right hand side on my homepage.

In which php source file are they located?

They are NOT modified by my theme.

Thank you.

Comment: it is part of your theme or plugin. wordpress by default don't show this kind of links and there is no "connect" in wordpress

Comment: @p.a. Please start following up on comments and answers to your questions - instead of adding new questions.